# Retain Directory Structure on exec within find application

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Trying to move files and folders from one directory to another on linux shell. The below command is working for me but its not re-creating the directory structure. Hope someone can help.

`find /var/spool/asterisk/monitor -iname ".wav" ! -name "-in.wav" ! -name "*-out.wav" -mtime +11 -exec cp {} /mnt/nfs/recordings/monitor \;`

Note: within the monitor folder there are various folders and sub folders.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'not re-creating the directory structure'. Are the files you are copying present more than one level from `/var/spool/asterisk/monitor`? i.e. in sub-levels?

Comment: so within /mnt/nfs/recordings/monitor we see all the files but not the original folder or subfolders the file was copied from. For example within /var/spool/asterisk/monitor there would be a folder structure like /companyid/date/time

Comment: So you want to retain a target directory structure as `/mnt/nfs/recordings/monitor/companyid/date/time/<file>` ?

Comment: that is correct thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use --parents in cp

```
find /var/spool/asterisk/monitor -iname ".wav" ! -name "-in.wav" ! -name "*-out.wav" -mtime +11 -exec cp --parents {} /mnt/nfs/recordings/monitor \;
```

Comment: This is exactly what is needed, but I suggest preserving the filename copying by adding `""` e.g. `"{}"` and you are missing a semi-colon at the last.

Comment: Agree with the missing colon (fixed), but the quotes around the "{}" seems unnecessary (filenames with spaces are copied OK). The substitution of {} is handled by find, not by the shell.

Comment: thanks guys, anyway to stop it creating the full directory structure ie: "\var\spool\asterisk\monitor"?

Comment: but do try it files having special characters too, before deciding that. dailing voting limit reached, can't upvote :(

Comment: @user3052324: before issuing the find command, cd to the "root" that you want to copy from, and give "." as your initial find directory.